# incrementing a variable every time in a for loop in jquery which is defined in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, sql

I have defined a variable $index in php section of my code

```
<pre>$quer = 'SELECT * FROM position WHERE profile_id = :nid';
$stnt = $pdo->prepare($quer);
$stnt->execute(array(':nid'=>$_GET['id']));
$posi = array();
while ($rows = $stnt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        $posi[] = $rows['year'];
    }
$index = 0;
</pre>
```

Until now I have an array named `$posi` which contain all values of years in database.

I am also creating an html element dynamically using jquery code which is shown in the attached image.

Now i am including that index value in html input element which is dynamically created but i want to increment index every time as for loop is getting incremented.

How can i do that. thanks [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvRDc.jpg)

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. Please don't post images instead of code because it is not practical for anyone who wants to help you, please edit your answer to include the code you added as an image. Also mixing javascript with php is usually bad practice and a bad idea.

Comment: We're programmers, we can read. **Please** read about [why you shouldn’t upload images of code or errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) a

Comment: For your problem - 1) extract part generating HTML/JS code into a function/method, 2) within your while loop increment `$index` by `1` in each iteration, 3) still in the loop call that extracted function with `$index` as an argument.